# symfony project from git

Tags: git, symfony

Welcome ! 

I have created a symfony repo locally , and I want to test it on a new folder.
in the folder

> /usr/share/nginx/www/gitproject

, I have a .git folder 
and I have the remote repo in

> /usr/share/gitproject

I want to install the project in the folder

> /usr/share/nginx/www/project

I think my composer should be like this ?

```
{
    "require" : {
        "symfony/framework-standard-edition" : "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories" : [{
        "type" : "vcs",
        "url" : "/usr/share/nginx/www/gitproject/"
    }]
}
```

But I have a dependency problem when running `composer update`.
Problem 1

> ```
> - symfony/framework-standard-edition dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> no matching package found.
> ```

My Question is : What should I put in the composer , since my gitrepo depends on those vendors , and I think it would be ok to put just 1 dependency that dependson other vendors.

In other words , if A depends On B and B depends on C & D & E , you put only A in dependency and it gets all the dependecies.

Am I wrong?

**Appendix**

this is the composer file for the symfony project

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "matthecat/htmlcompressor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "salva/jshrink-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": ["Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"],
        "post-update-cmd": ["Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets", "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know my question is  a bit confusing, but I'm developing in a subdomain and I want to update the current project just from composer

Comment: Your goal is to have the same git project in two different folders?
Also I think that you are right when saying "if A depends On B and B depends on C & D & E , you put only A in dependency and it gets all the dependecies."

Comment: Actually, yes, I want to have it in two folders using git. 
I'm still struggling with the logic to do so, because it's quite tricky

Comment: Why don't you just checkout the first into the second? :p.
You just create a copy of the original. You `git init` in your second dicrectory, then you `git clone /usr/share/gitproject`? Then when you update your main git project, you can just `git pull` the changes.

Comment: What I want to do is to keep the src in the developement folder and if I want to update in the production environement , i would update it through composer

Answer (score 1):

You should add all the requirements to your new composer :

```
{
    "require" : {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.4",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "matthecat/htmlcompressor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "salva/jshrink-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-standard-edition" : "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories" : [{
        "type" : "vcs",
        "url" : "/usr/share/nginx/www/gitneargood/"
    }]
}
```

Comment: why is that? when I add some bundles into my sf2 app, I don't care about their dependencies. Why does he have to copy all the Sf dependencies in a new composer.json?

Comment: I think I can answer you that , it's because the folder is empty and there are no vendors..

Comment: The thing is I don't think this answer is correct. There is nothing explained and it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should create project with:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject/ ~2.5
```

(see http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html).
*create-project* is more than just require the package and this is the preferred way to install symfony.

The reason why composer can not find mongo package is default stability:

> **minimum-stability (root-only)#**
>
> This defines the default behavior for filtering packages by stability. This defaults to stable, so if you rely on a dev package, you should specify it in your file to avoid surprises.

(more: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).